# AWS PHP S3 stream wrapper server side encryption

Tags: php, amazon-s3, stream, wrapper, aws-sdk

While using aws/aws-sdk-php(:2.*), I have registered the S3 stream wrapper in order to use the native PHP file functions in conjunction with 's3://' streams.

Question:
Is there a way I can enable server-side encryption when putting objects to S3 via the native PHP functions?
By default the objects get stored to S3 without any encryption.

As a side note, the application is using ZF1 Zend_File_Transfer to upload files from a form.

Comment: If you're uploading files from a form, why not have the client upload directly to S3?  Save you the bandwidth and effort.

Answer (score 2):

Use **stream_context_create** with fopen:

```
$s3FilePath = "s3://yourbucket/folder/file";
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    's3' => array('ServerSideEncryption' => 'AES256')
));
$stream = fopen($s3FilePath, 'w', false, $context);
fwrite($stream, "Your Data");
fclose($stream);
```

Alternatively you could use a bucket policy.